# Name of control for toggle boxes in sharepoint editor part

Tags: sharepoint, controls, web-parts

I'm trying to modify the EditorPart controller for my web part. Basically what I want is to have my custom controls inside a box like the standard properties that can toggle between visible and hidden.

[image]

I've been googling for a while, but I cannot seem to find an answer.

**Just to clarify:** I know I can use the Category property to accomplish this when adding web part properties directly to the web part, but I've extended the EditorPart controller and so I don't think I can simply add [Category("Feed settings")] to the TextBox and LiteralControls I'm creating (correct?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd need for a standard property is to mark it with the Category attribute:

```
[Category("My Category")]
public string FeedQuery { get; set; }
```

(You'll need to add the System.ComponentModel namespace to your class file).

For editor parts it is not so simple.  It appears that you can't add them to the standard categories. It is possible to style the editor part to resemble the OOB panels [as shown here](http://blog.techardinal.com/2009/09/09/advanced-editor-parts--style-and-grace.aspx)

Comment: I know this will work for web parts, but I'm extending EditorPart to have more fine grained control over what is displayed. Can I use this attribute here and if so where would I put it?

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a simple control you could use, but I guess I'll have to create my own :(

Comment: At the bottom of the post, one of the comments referred to Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.TPPanel, but it's an internal class so you have to instantiate it using reflection.  It looks OK...